# Get All TextField values from loop in Next.js when I press Submit button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui, vercel

first of all look at these below screenshots:
[image]

[image]

There are two tasks which I want to achieve:

1. There are two questions shown on the page using the array map method, by default I'm showing only one question, and when I press the next part button the second question will appear with the same question and a TextField (multiline). Now I've implemented a word counter in TextField but when I type something in 1st question the counter works properly. But when I go to the next question the here counter shows the previous question's word counter value, I want them to separately work for both questions.
2. When I click on the next part and again when I click on the previous part then the values from TextField are removed automatically. I want the values there if I navigate to the previous and next part questions. Also, I want to get both TextField values for a form submission when I press the Submit Test button.

> Below are my codes for this page. I'm using Next.js and MUI

```
import { Grid, Typography, Box, NoSsr, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import Timer from '../../../components/timer';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos';
import axios from '../../../lib/axios';
import { decode } from 'html-entities';
import { blueGrey } from '@mui/material/colors';

export default function Writing({ questions }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [show1, setShow1] = useState(true);

    const [showQuestionCounter, setShowQuestionCounter] = useState(0);
    const [wordsCount, setWordsCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ background: blueGrey[900] }}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                            <Grid item xs={4} display="flex" alignItems="center">
                                <PersonIcon
                                    sx={{ background: '#f2f2f2', borderRadius: '50px' }}
                                />
                                <Typography variant="h6" color="#f2f2f2" ml={1}>
                                    xxxxx xxxxx-1234
                                </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={4} container justifyContent="center">
                                <Timer timeValue={2400} />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={4} container justifyContent={'right'}>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    style={{ background: 'white', color: 'black' }}
                                    size="small">
                                    Settings
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    style={{
                                        background: 'white',
                                        color: 'black',
                                        margin: '0px 10px',
                                    }}
                                    size="small">
                                    Hide
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    style={{ background: 'white', color: 'black' }}
                                    size="small">
                                    Help
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>

            <Box
                sx={{
                    background: blueGrey[50],
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'absolute',
                }}
                pt={{ xs: 13, sm: 11, md: 10, lg: 11, xl: 11 }}>
                {questions.map((question, index) =>
                    index === showQuestionCounter ? (
                        <Box
                            key={question.id}
                            px={3}
                            sx={{ background: '#f2f2f2', pb: 4 }}
                            position={{
                                xs: 'sticky',
                                sm: 'sticky',
                                lg: 'initial',
                                md: 'initial',
                                xl: 'initial',
                            }}>
                            <Box
                                style={{ background: '#f7fcff', borderRadius: '4px' }}
                                py={1}
                                px={2}>
                                <Box>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h6" ml={1}>
                                        Part {question.id}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="div" ml={1} mt={1}>
                                        <NoSsr>
                                            <div
                                                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                                    __html: decode(question.questions[0].question, {
                                                        level: 'html5',
                                                    }),
                                                }}></div>
                                        </NoSsr>
                                    </Typography>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>

                            <Box
                                style={{
                                    background: '#f7fcff',
                                    borderRadius: '4px',
                                    marginBottom: '75px',
                                }}
                                pt={1}
                                px={3}
                                mt={{ xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 2, lg: 0, xl: 3 }}>
                                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} lg={6} md={6} xl={6}>
                                        <Box
                                            py={{ lg: 1, md: 1, xl: 1 }}
                                            style={{ height: '50vh' }}>
                                            <Scrollbars universal>
                                                <Typography
                                                    variant="body1"
                                                    component="div"
                                                    style={{ textAlign: 'justify' }}
                                                    mr={2}>
                                                    <NoSsr>
                                                        <div
                                                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                                                __html: decode(question.question_text, {
                                                                    level: 'html5',
                                                                }),
                                                            }}></div>
                                                    </NoSsr>
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Scrollbars>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid
                                        item
                                        xs={12}
                                        sm={12}
                                        lg={6}
                                        md={6}
                                        xl={6}
                                        mt={{ md: 4, lg: 4, xl: 4 }}>
                                        <TextField
                                            id={`${question.id}`}
                                            label="Type your answer here"
                                            multiline
                                            name={`answer_${question.id}`}
                                            rows={12}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            fullWidth
                                            helperText={`Words Count: ${wordsCount}`}
                                            onChange={(e) => {
                                                setWordsCount(
                                                    e.target.value.trim().split(/\s+/).length
                                                );
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    ) : null
                )}

                <Box sx={{ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
                    <Grid
                        container
                        style={{ background: blueGrey[300], display: 'flex' }}
                        py={2}
                        px={3}>
                        <Grid
                            item
                            xs={3}
                            sm={3}
                            lg={6}
                            md={6}
                            xl={6}
                            container
                            justifyContent={'start'}>
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                style={{ background: 'white', color: 'black' }}
                                size="small">
                                Save Draft
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            item
                            xs={9}
                            sm={9}
                            lg={6}
                            md={6}
                            xl={6}
                            container
                            justifyContent={'end'}>
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                size="small"
                                style={{
                                    background: 'white',
                                    color: 'black',
                                    visibility: show1 ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
                                }}
                                endIcon={<ArrowForwardIosIcon />}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setShow((prev) => !prev);
                                    setShowQuestionCounter(showQuestionCounter + 1);
                                    setShow1((s) => !s);
                                }}>
                                Next Part
                            </Button>
                            {show && (
                                <>
                                    <Box>
                                        <Button
                                            variant="contained"
                                            style={{
                                                background: 'white',
                                                color: 'black',
                                                margin: '0 10px',
                                                visibility: show ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
                                            }}
                                            startIcon={<ArrowBackIosIcon />}
                                            size="small"
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setShow1((s) => !s);
                                                setShowQuestionCounter(showQuestionCounter - 1);
                                                setShow((prev) => !prev);
                                            }}>
                                            previous Part
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button variant="contained" color="success">
                                            Submit Test
                                        </Button>
                                    </Box>
                                </>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { id } = context.query;
    const token = context.req.cookies.token;

    if (!token) {
        context.res.writeHead(302, {
            Location: '/',
        });
        context.res.end();
    }

    const res = await axios.get(`test/${id}/questions`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });
    if (res.data.success) {
        return {
            props: {
                questions: res.data.data.questions,
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `wordsCount` state is shared between both questions, which means that when you go to the next question the state remains unchanged and shows the `wordsCount` from the first question. To solve it, each question needs to have it's own state which you can do by creating a `Question` component and mapping over it:

```
export default function Question({ question }) {
  const [wordsCount, setWordsCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <Box
      // ...
    >
      {/* ... */}
      <TextField
        // ...
        helperText={`${wordsCount} words`}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setWordsCount(e.target.value.trim().split(/\s+/).length)
        }}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Then map over it:

```
{questions.map((question, index) =>
   index === showQuestionCounter ? (
     <Question key={question.id} question={question} />
   ) : null
)}
```

2. Currently, the value of `TextField` gets reset you the component is unmounted (i.e. when you go to the next question). You need to make the `TextField` component a [controlled component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled), meaning that you store the value of the field in `useState`. And if you need to submit the value of `TextField` later, then you probably need to store the values in the parent component:

```
export default function Writing({ questions }) {
  // ...
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([])

  function handleChange(id, answer) {
    // copy the current answers
    let newAnswers = [...answers]
    // find the index of the id of the answer in the current answers
    const index = newAnswers.findIndex((item) => item.id === id)
    // if the answer does exist, replace the previous answer with the new one, else add the new answer
    if (index) {
      newAnswers[index] = { id, answer }
      setAnswers(newAnswers)
    } else {
      setAnswers([...answers, { id, answer }])
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
        {/* ... */}
        {questions.map((question, index) =>
          index === showQuestionCounter ? (
            <Question
              key={question.id}
              question={question}
              value={answers.find((item) => item.id === question.id)?.answer || ''}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          ) : null
        )}
  </>
}
```

In the `Question` component, add the handler.

```
export default function Question({ question, value, handleInputChange }) {
  const [wordsCount, setWordsCount] = useState(0)

  return (
      <Box>
        {/* ... */}
        <TextField
          helperText={`${wordsCount} words`}
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleInputChange(question.id, e.target.value)
            setWordsCount(e.target.value.trim().split(/\s+/).length)
          }}
        />
        {/* ... */}
      </Box>
  )
}
```

In the parent component (`Writing`) you should be able to use the values for form submission.

Comment: everything is fine but when I use `value` props inside TextField then I'm able to write inside the TextField.

Comment: When I used defaultValue in TextField and also increase the `index+1` then now working fine.